# Update multiple nested fields mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, nosql

I have document with following structure

```
"_id": 1,
"params": {
    "defaults": {},
    "custom": {
        "one": true,
        "two": true,
        "three": false
    }
}
```

I want to update all **params.custom** fields with "on" values if they are true or "off" values if they are false. *Custom* may contain different fields or be empty at all, also params might not be present. How to update all documents due to this requirement?

Comment: Which means to say that unfortunately this "switch-flipping" operation would require each document to be read and the fields inspected before setting them to the reverse value. So for whatever document(s) need to be affected, it's a process of looping each document and writing back for each one as well.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, currently I am doing this operation one-by-one for each document as in your comment. I was curious if there is an easier way to achieve this

Comment: If there was then the question you were linked to here would be updated with a better approach and I would supect that solution would be highly upvoted if not changed to the accepted answer. That is generally the case, and just because something was posted years ago does not mean that it is not the most current approach to handling this.